How to update fields in a Word document
I'm new to Office Web Add-Ins (having come from VSTO land), so I'm probably not understanding something small and silly..
-- Edited and simplified --
I'm trying to get the following sample code to work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.field?view=word-js-preview#word-word-field-updateresult-member(1)
Test scenario:

Create a word document

Add some text

Insert  a 'NumWords' field

Insert some more text

Select the field

Run the following code
 export async function UpdateAllFields_Click(event: Office.AddinCommands.Event) {
   await Word.run(async (context) => {
     console.log("UpdateAllFields_Click");

     let field = context.document.getSelection().fields.getFirstOrNullObject();
     field.load(["code", "result", "type", "locked"]);

     await context.sync();

     if (field.isNullObject) {
       console.log("No field in selection.");
     } else {
       console.log(
         "Before updating:",
         "Code of first field: " + field.code,
         "Result of first field: " + JSON.stringify(field.result)
       );

       field.updateResult();
       field.select();
       await context.sync();

       field.load(["code", "result"]);
       await context.sync();

       console.log(
         "After updating:",
         "Code of first field: " + field.code,
         "Result of first field: " + JSON.stringify(field.result)
       );
     }

     await context.sync();
   }).catch(function (error) {
     console.log("error: " + error);
     if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
       console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
     }
   });

   event.completed();
 }



Can anyone explain why the 'field.updateResult()' command causes an exception when the context.sync() runs?
Code ='GeneralException'
errorLocation ='Field.updateResult'

You have calls of context.sync inside loops. Fix this before you do anything else. That may be all you need to get your code to work. See Avoid using the context.sync method in loops.

Thanks for linking that article. I have updated my code. And created a new test scenario.
Can you tell me why my code does nothing?

I'm having trouble getting the documented sample to work. I'll redo my question.

Using the example that you linked to in Script Lab, I can't reproduce this. The console output is exactly as expected. No error. The displayed value of the NUMPAGE stays at "1" of course because it is not moving to another page.

UPDATE: If I press the "Toggle ..." locked button in the example that you linked to, which is the "Manage Fields" example in Script Lab, this locks the field and then pressing the button to update the field does give me your error. You can't update a locked field. Somehow you have inadvertently locked it.

Sorry. I intended to write NUMWORDS, not NUMPAGES.

I can confirm that the fields are not locked.

Thanks, I should have tried Script Lab earlier. The code works fine in Script Lab, but not in my addin.. Any idea where I should start looking to see what's wrong with my addin?

The code works in a TaskPane but not when run as a function from a Ribbon button. It would appear that the context is different. Any idea why this would be the case?

If the SEQ fields are all literally copies of the first one, then they will all always have the same value. The second, etc. fields must use the \n option to indicate that the value should be incremented. Like this:
{SEQ Test * MERGEFORMAT}
{SEQ Test \n * MERGEFORMAT}
{SEQ Test \n * MERGEFORMAT}

Not true. Please copy/paste your first field 10 times (using Word for Windows), select everything and press F9. The numbers update to 1, 2, 3 etc

Regardless, my issue is with the UpdateResult() command. I can't get it to work. I have reworded the question.

@MattFitzmaurice I tried that. I got ten fields with the value "1", which is exactly what you seemed to say you were getting in the original version of your question. Without the \n, the fields don't increment.

Thanks. Here's a video showing that you don't need the \n. Unfortunately the Xbox Video recorder doesn't capture dialogs and context menus..
The last action that I do is right click >Update Fields.
https://templabee.sharepoint.com/:v:/s/Jacobs/EXexRDq4t2BHuejodL7AAHwBaTyZUggRzxzr5ht-C2NyYg?e=q4tAXc
